# How to connect several disconnected high density regions (of same color) in ListContourPlot?

Tags: plotting, listplot3d

Below (left) is my plot with "disconnected" high-value regions (red and blue). I want it to be "connected" (or interpolated) in regions without the data to have continuous red and other colour bands, as shown on the right plot.

I am using the `ListContourPlot` function, and I have already tried the `InterpolationOrder`, `MaxPlotPoints`, and Contours options, but they do not give me the desired result.

```
 leftPlot = ListContourPlot[LeftData1, PlotRange -> {{320, 350}, {60, 75}, All}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic]

rightPlot = ListContourPlot[RightData2, PlotRange -> {{320, 350}, {60, 75}, All}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

LeftData1=https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/eb1e5595-6d17-4753-96a2-627913a643c4

RightData2=https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/53da11c3-e8b5-4a38-a85a-7fcabfbeb8e8

[image]

Comment: At a minimum, share the data and commands you used to generate the plot with the undesirable features.

Comment: I have edited my post adding more information. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: ListContourPlot works with a list of points. Everywhere other than those points are "regions without data", which ListContourPlot interpolates. So I don't understand what you're after. Can you add a simpler example, e.g., points sampled from two separated Gaussian distributions which will give two "hills" separated by a "valley". Then show what you'd like to see for that simpler case?

Comment: Thanks for understanding the problem. I agree with you. For the simple case that you mentioned, my question: Is it possible to neglect the region (or interpolate it in some way) so that where there are no data points (valley), they connect the same height peaks (hill) to show a continuous high-density region instead of peaking discontinuously.